# Can I specify a redirected input before a compound command?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

Bash lets you specify a redirected input before a command:

```
$ <lines sed 's/^/line: /g'
line: foo
line: bar
```

Bash also lets you redirect input to a compound command like a `while` loop:

```
$ while read line; do echo "line: $line"; done <lines
line: foo
line: bar
```

However, when I try to specify a redirected input before a `while` loop, I get a syntax error:

```
$ <lines while read line; do echo "line: $line"; done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

What's wrong with this? Is it not possible to specify a redirected input before a compound command in Bash? If so, why not?

Comment: (I specifically want to know because I'm directing a command's output to a while loop in the current shell context via process substitution, and I'd prefer it if the first part of the code didn't have to appear *after* the second part.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`man bash` says:

> ... redirection  operators  may  precede  or  appear anywhere within a [simple command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Commands.html) or may follow a command.

`while` is not a simple command.

Comment: Aw man. ([Definition of simple commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Commands.html))

Answer (score 7):

You can in `zsh`, not in `bash` and [choroba has already pointed you to the documentation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156049/22565), but if you want to have the redirection before, you can do things like:

```
< file eval '
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    ...
  done'
```

Or (on systems with support for `/dev/fd/n`):

```
< file 3<< 'EOF' . /dev/fd/3
while IFS= read -r line; do
  ...
done
EOF
```

(not that's you'd want to do it).

You can also do:

```
exec 3< file
while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
  ...
done
exec 3<&-
```

(note that `exec` will exit the script if `file` can't be open).

Or use a function:

```
process()
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    ...
  done

< file process
```

Comment: Wonder if `eval` and `/dev/fd/` routes are equally fast.

Comment: @DeerHunter, `<< EOF` involves creating a temp file, filing it up and then open it, read it and interpret as you read it. It's bound to be less fast, though probably not noticeably as it's all going to happen in memory anyway.

Comment: "Use a function" doesn't really help - I still have to write the function before the code that gets directed into it (although I suppose I can write a function for that, with the two functions in either order).

Comment: `command exec` can handle the exit issue as w/ other builtins. but it gets in way too late too handle the reserved word bits.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas What's the reason for using a temporary file rather than a pipe?

Comment: @kasperd, that should be a separate question, but a pipe involves forking an additional process to feed the other end so is generally less efficient. Having said that, `rc`/`es` and `ash` use a pipe there, though they are in minority (`ash` doesn't fork an additional process unless the content doesn't fit in the pipe buffer though)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas In typical use cases there would be no need to `fork`. Instead of the shell calling `wait` to wait for the child process to terminate, it could write all the data to the pipe, and then call `wait`. Using `fork` would only be needed, if the shell need to keep running with the child continuing in the background. Detecting when `fork` is needed is slightly tricky. It would be simpler to always `fork`, that is also simpler to implement than a temporary file, and less prone to security bugs. And with CoW `fork` shouldn't be a major performance problem.

Comment: @kasperd, yes, that's how ash works. It does nor fork except when necessary, but forking has side effects (co-holds file descriptors for instance) as well and possible security implications. While the temp file is something that is proven as it has been used for over 35 years (note that the temp file is deleted _before_ being filled up). It also has the benefit of being seekable. There's good and less good in both approaches.

Answer (score 3):

You can use that substitution, if you want to precede the input:

```
cat lines | while read line; do echo "line: $line"; done
```

Comment: I need this to be executed within the current shell context - no pipelines. (The code in the question was just a simplified example.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use exec to redirect the stdin.

In a script:

```
exec < <(cat lines)
while read line ; do echo "line: $line"; done
```

You can't use in a login shell though (it will dump the file on the stdout and exit). In that case you can open a different file descriptor:

```
exec 3< <(cat lines)
while read -u 3 line ; do echo "line: $line"; done
```

For reference: [Using exec](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17974.html)

Comment: And if I'm using stdin for something else I ihave to surround the code in `exec 3<&0` and `exec <&3`, right? (that or use &3 for the redirect ie. your second example)

Comment: Yes, you "save" the current stdin to another file descriptor and when you finished you can restore it. (it's well explained in the first example in the linked doc)